# Pythonic way to find and replace with a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
dic = {
'foo': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
'bar': ['four', 'five', 'six'],
'baz': ['seven', 'eight', 'nine']
}
```

and from this list:

```
my_list = ['one', 'five', 'nine']
```

I want to search the corresponding key in the dictionary in order to get this new list:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

My actual working code is:

```
l = []
for el in my_list:
    for d_key, d_val in dic.items():
        if el in d_val:
            l.append(d_key)

print(l)
```

But I think there is a more Pythonic way. Any ideas?

---

**edit:**

Thanks to TigerhawkT3's suggestion (*Readability counts, but practicality beats purity*), I chosen to reverse my dictionary in order to directly get the values. Now my code looks like:

```
dic = {'one': 'foo', 'two': 'foo', 'three': 'foo', 'four': 'bar', 'five': 'bar', 'six': 'bar', 'seven': 'baz', 'nine': 'baz', 'eight': 'baz'}
my_list = ['one', 'five', 'nine']
print([dic[x] for x in my_list])
```

Comment: You're looking up values to get a key. That's the opposite of dictionaries' intended use.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am not sure if this is a valid duplicate because both the dict value  and "my_list" are list.

Comment: If there are multiple terms to look up, just loop over them. "You can put this into a loop to repeat it" doesn't add anything difficult or unique - the methods in the linked question can be easily applied to this task.

Comment: TigerhawkT3: In fact there are a lot of values for each key, so I don't want a long code like `'one': 'foo', 'two': 'foo', 'three': 'foo', 'xxx': 'foo', ...`. That's why I used this data structure.

Comment: Given that the answer you just accepted _reverses the original dictionary into exactly that_, I don't understand your complaint...

Comment: The code is shorter and data are more intelligible.

Comment: I still don't understand. Did you just want a more concise way of expressing the dictionary you actually wanted to use? Readability counts, but practicality beats purity. If your data structures are pretty but backwards, what's the point?

Comment: Ok, I assume your right, I reversed my dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first reverse the dictionary:

```
invdic = {val: key for key in dic for val in dic[key]}
```

Then you can apply the substitution:

```
l = ['one', 'five', 'nine']
l = list(invdic[x] for x in l)
print(l)
```

**EDIT**: If you need to leave the keyword as is, when the dictionary does not contain the match, you can replace the second line with:

```
l = list(invdic.get(x, x) for x in l)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) to check if the a key value has a common element with your tuple.

```
>>> s = set(my_list)
>>> [key for key, value in dic.items() if not s.isdisjoint(value)]
['foo', 'baz', 'bar']
```

If the order of the key matter then:

```
>>> [key for item in my_list for key, value in dic.items() if item in value]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```